# Update editing style of UITableViewCell depending on contents

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I am creating a table-based interface similar to iPad Contacts, in which the user can add to a list of rows by tapping a blank row at the bottom.  The table is always in editing mode, and non-blank rows should have a standard delete editing icon to the left.  As soon as the user starts typing in the last blank row, a delete icon should be added to the left (and a new blank row added).

Does anyone know how to make the UITableView update the editing style on demand?  Everything works, except that the delete icon doesn't appear until the user scrolls the row out of view and then back into view.

Here's my editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (/* text field contains data */)
   {
      return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
   }
   else
   {
      return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fought this same problem yesterday. You basically have to toggle the table view's editing mode property. After you do that, it will refresh your cell's editingStyle.

Here's the code that does the trick for me:

```
self.tableView.editing = NO;
self.tableView.editing = YES;
```

This gives what appears to me to be the exact same sort of effect as the contacts app. At a minimum, it will refresh your editingStyle.

Comment: That works, thank you!  Maybe I should ask this in a new question, but did you also find a way to remove the active responder UITextField's cursor when the delete icon is tapped, as Contacts does?

Comment: No, I never looked at doing that since it wasn't something I was really concerned with handling.

Comment: Wish I'd found this a couple of hours ago.

Comment: One follow up: this will send didTransitionToState to your cells and, if they're like mine and toggle enabled on any controls, you'll lose first responder again. I have to go through the visible cells and tell them to ignore didTransitionToState while I'm turning editing off and on. A bit of a pain, but doable.

Comment: what i've done is to returned NO from textFieldShouldEndEditing: while setting tableView.editing to YES/NO. It seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the row being edited.  (I'm not sure if that will mess up the first responder status on your text field or not.)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that does mess up the first responder.