# Set editing style on a UITableViewCell without reloading the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm building a view controller that is very similar to the Contacts app ABPersonViewController in editing mode.

I have a UITableView filled with Custom UITableViewCells which contain a UITextField where the user can enter a phone number

I have a situation where if someone starts entering in a new phone number (in the last cell of the section), a new empty table view cell is added to the bottom of the table, and the editing style of the current table view cell is set to UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete, like in the Contacts app in the same situation.

My problem is that I don't know how to change the editing style of the UITableViewCell without reloading it. The problem with reloading it is that its UITextField that is currently being edited will be released, dismissing the keyboard.

Is there a way to change the editing style of the UITableViewCell without reloading it? Or another way of accomplishing what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by following the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664207/472344

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the `UITableViewCell` method `setEditing:animated:`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't have any effect on whether the delete button is showing when I call it.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully set editing cell with multiple selection applying below code:

```
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];    
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;  

    // Add these two lines can fix icon issue.(First time enter edit mode still show delete icon.)
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```